# How to use multiprocessing to parallelize two calls to the same function, with different arguments, in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, for-loop, multiprocessing

In a for loop, I am calling a function twice but with different argument sets (`argSet1`, `argSet2`) **that change on each iteration of the for loop**. I want to parallelize this operation since one set of the arguments causes the called function to run faster, and the other set of arguments causes a slow run of the function. Note that I **do not** want to have two for loops for this operation. I also have another requirement: Each of these functions will execute some parallel operations and therefore I do not want to have any of the functions with either `argSet1` or `argSet2` be running more than once, because of the computational limited resources that I have. Making sure that the function with both argument sets is running will help me utilize the CPU cores as much as possible. Here's how do it normally without parallelization:

```
def myFunc(arg1, arg2):
    if arg1:
        print ('do something that does not take too long')
    else:
       print ('do something that takes long')

for i in range(10):
    argSet1 = arg1Storage[i]
    argSet1 = arg2Storage[i]
    myFunc(argSet1)
    myFunc(argSet2)
```

This will definitely not take the advantage of the computational resources that I have. Here's my try to parallelize the operations:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def myFunc(arg1, arg2):
    if arg1:
        print ('do something that does not take too long')
    else:
       print ('do something that takes long')

for i in range(10):
    argSet1 = arg1Storage[i]
    argSet1 = arg2Storage[i]
    p1 = Process(target=myFunc, args=argSet1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=myFunc, args=argSet2)
    p2.start()
```

However, this way each function with its respective arguments will be called 10 times and things become extremely slow. Given my limited knowledge of multiprocessing, I tried to improve things a bit more by adding `p1.join()` and `p2.join()` to the end of the for loop but this still causes slow down as `p1` is done much faster and things wait until `p2` is done. I also thought about using `multiprocessing.Value` to do some communication with the functions but then I have to add a `while` loop inside the function for each of the function calls which slows down everything again. I wonder if someone can offer a practical solution?

Comment: Why do you call myFunc 10 times in a for loop per argSet if you only want to call it once?

Comment: @dnswlt Sorry my bad, had forgotten to mention that the arguments change on each iteration. Updated my question now

Comment: You should use a Pool of processes (however many you want), and submit all the jobs at the beginning, and let them all run to completion.  This way you can utilize all available cores for the entire run, whereas currently the faster of the two parallel jobs will finish first then nothing will be happening on that core.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thank you but could you please try posting an answer instead? I am pretty new to multiprocessing and do not clearly know how to do things with it properly.

Comment: I don't think you defined your requirements definitively enough. 1. You do not want to parallelize all the runs 2. You don't want to parallelize only 2 calls at a time (your last attempt). So what do you want? Parallelize all 10 fast calls at once, and sequentially run the slow ones? Run a slow call while running sequentially running fast runs in parallel? In this case, when the slow run ends do you want to go to the next slow run, still running fast in parallel?

Comment: @kabanus *Run a slow call while running sequentially running fast runs in parallel? In this case, when the slow run ends do you want to go to the next slow run, still running fast in parallel?*. Yes that's exactly what I want. I want to always have two parallel jobs running. If the slow one ends earlier, I want to run another slow job. Sorry for not being very clear

Comment: @Amir check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since I built this answer in patches, scroll down for the best solution to this problem**

You need specify to **exactly** how you want things to run. As far as I can tell, you want two processes to run at most, but also at least. Also, you do not want the heavy call to hold up the fast ones. One simple non-optimal way to run is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func(counter,somearg):
    j = 0
    for i in range(counter): j+=i
    print(somearg)

def loop(counter,arglist):
    for i in range(10):
        func(counter,arglist[i])

heavy = Process(target=loop,args=[1000000,['heavy'+str(i) for i in range(10)]])
light = Process(target=loop,args=[500000,['light'+str(i) for i in range(10)]])
heavy.start()
light.start()
heavy.join()
light.join()
```

The output here is (for one example run):

```
light0
heavy0
light1
light2
heavy1
light3
light4
heavy2
light5
light6
heavy3
light7
light8
heavy4
light9
heavy5
heavy6
heavy7
heavy8
heavy9
```

You can see the last part is sub-optimal, since you have a sequence of heavy runs - which means there is one process instead of two.

An easy way to optimize this, if you can estimate how much longer is the heavy process running. If it's twice as slow, as here, just run 7 iterations of heavy first, join the light process, and have it run the additional 3.

Another way is to run the heavy process in pairs, so at first you have 3 processes until the fast process ends, and then continues with 2.

**The main point** is separating the heavy and light calls to another process entirely - so while the fast calls complete one after the other quickly you can work your slow stuff. Once th fast ends, it's up to you how elaborate do you want to continue, but I think for now estimating how to break up the heavy calls is good enough. This is it for my example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func(counter,somearg):
    j = 0
    for i in range(counter): j+=i
    print(somearg)

def loop(counter,amount,arglist):
    for i in range(amount):
        func(counter,arglist[i])

heavy1 = Process(target=loop,args=[1000000,7,['heavy1'+str(i) for i in range(7)]])
light = Process(target=loop,args=[500000,10,['light'+str(i) for i in range(10)]])
heavy2 = Process(target=loop,args=[1000000,3,['heavy2'+str(i) for i in range(7,10)]])
heavy1.start()
light.start()
light.join()
heavy2.start()
heavy1.join()
heavy2.join()
```

with output:

```
light0
heavy10
light1
light2
heavy11
light3
light4
heavy12
light5
light6
heavy13
light7
light8
heavy14
light9
heavy15
heavy27
heavy16
heavy28
heavy29
```

Much better utilization. You can of course make this more advanced by sharing a queue for the slow process runs, so when the fast are done they can join as workers on the slow queue, but for only two different calls this may be overkill (though not much harder using the [queue](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/queue.html#queue.Queue)). The **best solution**:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue,Process
import queue

def func(index,counter,somearg):
    j = 0
    for i in range(counter): j+=i
    print("Worker",index,':',somearg)

def worker(index):
    try:
        while True:
            func,args = q.get(block=False)
            func(index,*args)
    except queue.Empty: pass

q = Queue()
for i in range(10):
    q.put((func,(500000,'light'+str(i))))
    q.put((func,(1000000,'heavy'+str(i))))

nworkers = 2
workers = []
for i in range(nworkers):
    workers.append(Process(target=worker,args=(i,)))
    workers[-1].start()
q.close()
for worker in workers:
    worker.join()
```

This is the best and most scalable solution for what you want. Output:

```
Worker 0 : light0
Worker 0 : light1
Worker 1 : heavy0
Worker 1 : light2
Worker 0 : heavy1
Worker 0 : light3
Worker 1 : heavy2
Worker 1 : light4
Worker 0 : heavy3
Worker 0 : light5
Worker 1 : heavy4
Worker 1 : light6
Worker 0 : heavy5
Worker 0 : light7
Worker 1 : heavy6
Worker 1 : light8
Worker 0 : heavy7
Worker 0 : light9
Worker 1 : heavy8
Worker 0 : heavy9
```

Comment: Very good answer! Thank you! I think the `Queue` solution is more applicable to my work.

Comment: @Amir, it's the "proper" solution. And will work better for different amount of jobs and workers. It's the classic mode of work when you just want to "feed" jobs to "workers".

Comment: I have just realized an issue with all of these approaches. I turns out that the function that I am running is a function inside a class (`myClass.myFunc`). In the class `__init__(self)`  I define some variables (imagine they are like counters). Then the inside function (which I want to parallelize) updates those variables and I want to use them outside of the `myClass.myFunc` call. However, since `Process` somehow makes its own environment I cannot use those variables outside of the class. I'm sorry for the adding more complexity to the problem, but is there a solution for this?

Comment: It doesn't have to use multiprocessing but  I just do not want to use threads since threads will not use all available cores (as far as I know).

Comment: @Amir You want a shared counter among all the processes (so shared memory but not threading)? This is important. Check [https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html] and search for shared memory - looks like you want to use [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) as your global counter.

Comment: The *inside* variables might be objects too which makes the problem harder :/ Any solution for resolving this issue for objects, but not just variables?

Comment: @Amir you keep adding new requirements to the question, and this is devolving into a chat. What do you mean by "inside"? I suggest this - you solved your mode of work, and now you want to ask about shared memory. Write a new question involving only two processes and how you want them to share memory (so simplify away the hard/light process problem we solved here) - link it here and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a `multiprocessing.Pool` of processes and map your `myFunc` into it, like so:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def myFunc(arg1, arg2):
    if arg1:
        print ('do something that does not take too long')
        time.sleep(0.01)
    else:
       print ('do something that takes long')
       time.sleep(1)

def wrap(args):
    return myFunc(*args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool()
    argStorage = [(True, False), (False, True)] * 12
    p.map(wrap, argStorage)
```

I added a `wrap` function, since the function passed to `p.map` must accept a single argument. You could just as well adapt `myFunc` to accept a tuple, if that's possible in your case.

My sample `appStorage` constists of 24 items, where 12 of them will take 1sec to process, and 12 will be done in 10ms. In total, this script runs in 3-4 seconds (I have 4 cores).

Answer (score 0):

One possible implementation could be as follow:

```
import concurrent.futures
import math

list_of_args = [arg1, arg2]

def my_func(arg):
    ....
    print ('do something that takes long')

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for arg, result in zip(list_of_args, executor.map(is_prime, list_of_args)):
            print('my_func({0}) => {1}'.format(arg, result))
```

`executor.map` is like the built in function, the map method allows multiple calls to a provided function, passing each of the items in an iterable to that function.